# Possible reasons for field GOR being below Solution GOR(Rs)

Tags: petroleum

It has been noticed in the field multiple times that the field produced GOR is well below the Solution GOR (obtained from PVT properties).
Based on Industry observed production data globally, I would like to know the possible reasons from both reservoir and production engineering perspectives that can lead to such discrepancies .
Further, please indicate any specific algorithms/concepts which can help mitigate the effect of the above mentioned discrepancy in the allocation of the monthly gas production volumes.

Can you to please take some time from your busy schedule and provide the answer to the question.

Thanks in Advance!